# Generate the same random numbers in two separate matlab code files

Tags: matlab, random

I have two separate code files that apply different operations to the random numbers generated. My goal is to see what happens to these random numbers after each code is applied to them. I need the same random numbers to be generated in both code files so that I can compare the effect of the codes. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`rng`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) function to set the seed of the random number generator before you generate the random numbers.

```
rng(1); % set the seed to the same value in both codes
A = rand(5,1); % generate random numbers
```